# AS3 Save & Load multiple text boxs data to local file(s)

Tags: forms, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a form in flash (AS3) that can save data / text from multiple dynamic text box's into a user specified path & local file & also load any saved forms back into appropriate text box's.  I have found some great examples on how to do this with a single text box. I know it should be simple however I cannot seem to figure it out or successfully mod existing examples to work with multiple text boxs?. any ideas?

Here's the code i'm currently using / trying to mod.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;

public class BinaryXMLTool extends Sprite 
{

    // ** minimalist buttons **
    private var browseButton:TextField;
    private var saveButton:TextField;

    // ** minimalist editor **
    private var xmlText:TextField;

    // ** browse/load/save **
    private var xmlFile:FileReference;

    public function BinaryXMLTool():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        // entry point
        stage.align         = StageAlign.LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode         = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.showDefaultContextMenu    = false;

        // ** draw minimalist text editor **
        xmlText             = new TextField();
        xmlText.multiline       = true;
        xmlText.background      = true;
        xmlText.backgroundColor     = 0xEEEEEE;
        xmlText.type            = TextFieldType.INPUT;
        xmlText.width           = 400;
        xmlText.height          = 400;
        xmlText.border          = true;
        xmlText.x           = 15;
        addChild(xmlText);

        // ** draw minimalist browse button **
        browseButton            = new TextField();
        browseButton.autoSize       = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        browseButton.background     = true;
        browseButton.backgroundColor    = 0x000000;
        browseButton.defaultTextFormat  = new TextFormat("Tahoma", 14, 0xFFFFFF, true, null, null, null, null, null, 4, 4);
        browseButton.selectable     = false;
        browseButton.text       = "BROWSE";
        browseButton.x          = (stage.stageWidth - browseButton.width) * 0.5;
        browseButton.y          = 420;
        addChild(browseButton);

        // ** draw minimalist save button **
        saveButton          = new TextField();
        saveButton.autoSize     = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        saveButton.background       = true;
        saveButton.backgroundColor  = 0xAAAAAA;
        saveButton.defaultTextFormat    = browseButton.defaultTextFormat;
        saveButton.selectable       = false;
        saveButton.text         = "SAVE";
        saveButton.x            = (stage.stageWidth - saveButton.width) * 0.5;
        saveButton.y            = 460;
        addChild(saveButton);

        // ** button listeners **
        browseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_buttonClick,     false, 0, true);
        saveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_buttonClick, false, 0, true);
    }

    /**
    * handle browse or save
    */
    private function on_buttonClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var btn:TextField = evt.target as TextField;
        if (btn)
        {
            if (btn.text == "BROWSE")
            {
                xmlFile = new FileReference();
                xmlFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, on_xmlSelect, false, 0, true);
                xmlFile.browse([new FileFilter("XML Documents","*.xml")]);
            }
            else if (btn.text == "SAVE")
            {
                if (xmlFile)
                {
                    if (xmlText.text.length)
                    {
                        // ** saving as binary **
                        var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        data.writeUTFBytes(xmlText.text);
                        data.compress();
                        new FileReference().save(data, "bin" + xmlFile.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
    * handle browse, load XML file
    */
    private function on_xmlSelect(evt:Event):void
    {
        xmlFile.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, on_xmlSelect);
        xmlFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_xmlComplete, false, 0, true);
        xmlFile.load();
    }

    /**
    * handle load, check if it is binary, uncompress, display XML in editor
    */
    private function on_xmlComplete(evt:Event):void
    {
        xmlFile.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_xmlComplete);

        saveButton.backgroundColor = 0x000000;

        var data:* = FileReference(evt.target).data;
        if (data is ByteArray)
        {
            try
            {
                ByteArray(data).uncompress();
            }
            catch(e:Error)
            {
            }

        }
        data = XML(data);
        xmlText.text = data;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Also its for a local office environment so unfortunately PHP isnt an option.

Comment: Ok, that example you found saves a single XML string to a file as zlib compressed bytes. In your case, you want to save "multiple text" values to a file; do care what file format? You could save it as a plain XML, or AMF (ActionScript Message Format), or something else.

Comment: I'm not bothered which file format it saves as.

Comment: To give you more of an idea of what I'm trying to create.  I need a digital version of a client details / signup form we use in-house.  Fields include Business Name, Contact Name, Phone, Mobile, Fax, Email, Web, etc.  sort of like an address book app.  Flash App will load a A4 sized / aspec ration JPG of our existing FORM and create 35 or more text boxs populated in their appropriate places on the page.  Need to be able to Populate ourselves save said data & loading said data back into appropriate text boxs.

Comment: Makes sense. I've posted an example that stores multiple textfield values to an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Flash Player you can save and load a local file using `FileReference/save()` and `load()`. However, this requires that the user choose the file location, and you have no control over it.

Alternatively, you can store data locally using `SharedObject`. This may require user permission, and it may be cleared by the user (purposefully or accidentally), for example through their browser's "clear local data" feature.

Using AIR, you can use the `File` class to read and write local files without any user interaction, or you can use `EncryptedLocalStore`.

(This question gets asked a lot, if you search around you will find more information.)

**EDIT:**

Looking at the example code you posted, it's expecting to write an XML string as zlib compressed bytes to a file. In your case, you want to save multiple values to a single file. You could do this by simply constructing a new XML object that contains those values, then read those values back out of the XML object. Here's an example that does this:

```
// Timeline instances
var textField1:TextField;
var textField2:TextField;
var saveBtn:SimpleButton;
var loadBtn:SimpleButton;

saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveClick);
function saveClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Save the state of both text fields
    save(textField1.text, textField2.text, "data.xml");
}

loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadClick);
function loadClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    load();
}

function save(text1:String, text2:String, defaultFileName:String):void {
    var xml:XML = <xml>
        <text1>{text1}</text1>
        <text2>{text2}</text2>
    </xml>;
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(xml, defaultFileName);
}

function load():void {
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.browse([new FileFilter("XML", "*.xml")]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, loadSelect);
}

function loadSelect(e:Event):void {
    var file:FileReference = e.target as FileReference;
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
    file.load();
}

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    var file:FileReference = e.target as FileReference;
    var xml:XML = XML(file.data.readUTFBytes(file.data.bytesAvailable));

    // Assign the loaded XML text values back to the text fields
    textField1.text = xml.text1;
    textField2.text = xml.text2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for your fast response.  For backup reasons & the fact that we will be saving multiple forms for editing and or printing at a later date SharedObject isnt an option.  I have been looking into FileRefrence/save() and load() and found a handy piece of code which works great, However I need to save multiple text boxs to a file, and would prefer to use my physically created text boxs rather than code created dynamic text inputs. (I will update my question with code i'm using / need to mod)

Comment: Yes you can use FileReference with timeline created textfields. I'll check out your code when you post it.

Comment: AWESOME !, that is exactly what I was looking for and So much more simple than the way I was attempting to achieve it. THANKS HEAPS Aaron you are a legend.